# can i store 'mode' in a variable and use it at fopen()

Tags: c

```
char mode;

printf("---------------------------------------")
scanf(" %c", mode);
FILE * fpointer = fopen("kkkkkkkk.txt", mode);`
```

I tried but no result. compiler doesn't gives me error but not getting the program run completely.

Comment: What unexpected behavior do you get? Please include the expected behavior and the actual behavior, including the full text of any errors.

Comment: You can, but the mode is a *string* (that is, a pointer to a zero-terminated `char` buffer), not a `char`.

Comment: Remember that you pass a *string* for the `fopen` mode, not a single `char` value. Also remember that the `%c` format for `scanf` expects a *pointer* to the `char` variable.

Comment: And the compiler should have warned you at least about the wrong argument for `fopen`. Compilers are also able to catch the mismatch in argument for `scanf`, but you might need to enable more warnings for that (which is a generally good idea).

Comment: What if the mode is not valid (for example `@`)?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

The second argument of `fopen(3)` should be a of type `const char *` (essentially, a string). However, you've used a single `char` which will not work. Also, I don't think you've initialised it. Here's a working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char mode[5];
  scanf("%s", mode);
  printf("Received mode is '%s'\n", mode);
  FILE *fp = fopen("sample.txt", mode);
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("Couldn't open file ");
  } else {
    printf("Done! Closing\n");
    fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

Here are two runs to indicate what's going on.

```
ن ./sample
r
Received mode is 'r'
Couldn't open file : No such file or directory
```

Opening it in `"r"` mode here. Since `sample.txt` doesn't exist, we get an error.

```
ن ./sample
w
Received mode is 'w'
Done! Closing

ن ./sample
r
Received mode is 'r'
Done! Closing
```

The first time, it opens in `"w"` mode and creates it. The next time, `"r"` will work since the `sample.txt` file exists.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. OP wants to dynamically change the mode based on the result from `scanf`

Comment: @mousetail I was highlighting the problem rather than providing a complete solution but I've updated the answer nonetheless.

Comment: why you suggest  * before mode?  Is * is a dereferencing? please explain...........bcz its working now

Comment: Loosely speaking,  a `char *` variable is a string whereas a `char` is a single character.

Answer (score 0):

The `mode` argument needs to be a *string*, not a single character, since you have modes like `r+`, `wb`, `wbx+`, etc.  So your `mode` variable needs to be an *array* of `char` that’s at least 5 elements wide:

```
char mode[5]; // up to 4 characters plus string terminator
```

You’d then use the `%s` conversion specifier with `scanf` (or, preferably, `fgets`) to read the input string:

```
#define MODE_LEN       4
#define FILENAME_LEN 255

FILE *fp = NULL;
char filename[FILENAME_LEN+1] = {0}; // +1 for string terminator
char mode[MODE_LEN+1] = {0};         // initialize to all 0

printf( "Gimme a file name: " );
if ( !fgets( filename, sizeof filename, stdin ) )
{
  // input error, bail out here
  exit( 0 );
}

printf( "Gimme the fopen mode: " );
if ( !fgets( mode, sizeof mode, stdin ) )
{
  // input error, bail out here
  exit( 0 );
}

fp = fopen( filename, mode );
if ( !fp )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Could not open %s with mode %s\n", 
    filename, mode );
  exit( 0 );
}

// read/write fp here

fclose( fp );
```